# question regarding while loops and variable indexing

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to coding, so forgive me if this is answered elsewhere. I am not sure what to search for to find a relevant answer. I also am not sure if my title is even correct. I want to print out each value in C_numbers that is associated with the same index in barcode_names. I want to separate these numbers each time the value in barcode_names changes. So I am using a third list unique_barcodes to compare to.

```
barcode_names = [1111,1111,1111,2222,2222,2222,3333,3333]
C_numbers = [12,5,7,28,32,13,2,9]
unique_barcodes = [1111,2222,3333]
x = 0
y = 0

for z in barcode_names:
    if barcode_names[x] == unique_barcodes[y]:
        print(C_numbers[x])
        x = x+1 
    else:
        y = y+1 
        print('next page')
result:
12
5
7
next page
28
32
13
next page
```

For some reason, it doesn't print the last two values 2 and 9. How do I get it to continue looping until it finishes printing all the values?

Comment: Your problem is that the loop only runs 8 times, as the length of `barcode_names`. On two of these times `x` does not increase and hence when the loop ends before `x` reaches the last two items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping over `barcode_names`, so the most iterations that loop can make is eight. Increasing `y` while printing `next page` counts as one of those iterations. This prevents you from doing the last two things you wanted to do, as then you'd need a total of ten iterations. To fix this, you need to keep looping as long as `x` is a valid index in `barcode_names`. Change `for z in barcode_names:` to `while x < len(barcode_names):`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `x` and `y` was throwing off your loop and is why it didn't complete.

Maybe something like this is more simple?

```
barcode_names = [1111,1111,1111,2222,2222,2222,3333,3333]
C_numbers = [12,5,7,28,32,13,2,9]
last_name = barcode_names[0]

for i in range(len(barcode_names)):
    barcode_name = barcode_names[i]
    if not barcode_name == last_name:
        last_name = barcode_name
        print('next page')
    print(C_numbers[i])

result:
12
5
7
next page
28
32
13
next page
2
9
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop control variable `z` is not stopping itself from being incremented when `y` index value is incrementing. Hence, before your desired print, the loop gets terminated.

I found this by adding the following line to your code inside the loop at the beginning

```
print('z value: ', z)
```

i.e. complete program becomes:

```
barcode_names = [1111,1111,1111,2222,2222,2222,3333,3333]
C_numbers = [12,5,7,28,32,13,2,9]
unique_barcodes = [1111,2222,3333]
x = 0
y = 0

for z in barcode_names:
    print('z value: ', z)
    if barcode_names[x] == unique_barcodes[y]:
        print(C_numbers[x])
        x = x+1 
    else:
        y = y+1 
        print('next page')
```

Output:

```
z value:  1111
12
z value:  1111
5
z value:  1111
7
z value:  2222
next page
z value:  2222
28
z value:  2222
32
z value:  3333
13
z value:  3333
next page
>
```

Try this instead:

```
barcode_names = [1111,1111,1111,2222,2222,2222,3333,3333]
C_numbers = [12,5,7,28,32,13,2,9]
unique_barcodes = [1111,2222,3333]
x = 0
y = 0

for z in barcode_names:
    # print('z value: ', z)
    if barcode_names[x] != unique_barcodes[y]:
        y = y+1 
        print('next page')
    print(C_numbers[x])
    x = x+1
```

Output:

```
12
5
7
next page
28
32
13
next page
2
9
>
```